# Specify url for a folder path in django

Tags: django

I would like to make a path to my 'downloads' folder, so that if a URL request like

```
http://<domain>/downloads/file.pdf
```

will make the particular file be downloaded.

Comment: What are you asking which is different to putting the file into a folder under your MEDIA_ROOT folder? Do you mean you want to use django to generate a PDF at that location?

Comment: No, I mean i have a pdf file in a folder inside my project folder and it should be accessible through a URL request.

Comment: If you've set up your project in the default configuration, and have configured your MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL correctly then it should just work. If not, please describe exactly what you've tried and copy in those particular settings for us to check.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off keeping your static media files together and reference them through STATIC_URL/MEDIA_URL.  However, let's say you are generating the *file.pdf* on a per-request basis and the information on it is dynamically generated.  Here is one way you may want to implement such behavior:

```
# urls.py
(r'^downloads/(?P<file_name>[-\w]+)/$', 'downloads.views.get_download'),

# downloads.views.py
def get_download(request, file_name=None):
    if file_name:
        response = MyPDFGenerator.objects.create_pdf(file_name)
        return response
    else:
        raise Http404
```